# How to execute a webpack module from a <script>?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've written an ES6 module that looks something like this:

```
export default function({makeCurrentVerUrl, verUrl, fileServer, downloadTokenType, appId}) {
    ...
}
```

When compiled by webpack, it looks something like this:

```
webpackJsonp([5,7],[
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    'use strict';

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: true
    });

    exports.default = function (_ref) {
        var makeCurrentVerUrl = _ref.makeCurrentVerUrl;
        var verUrl = _ref.verUrl;
        var fileServer = _ref.fileServer;
        var downloadTokenType = _ref.downloadTokenType;
        var appId = _ref.appId;

        ...
    };

/***/ }
]);
```

Which is great, but I'm not sure how to run this file and call my default function.

I can include it,

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Which I believe will run it automatically, but how can I call the functions I've defined in it from the browser? `require` is not defined in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the easiest way to do this without changing `output.library` (assuming you don't want to globalize *everything*) is to just attach your needed functions to the `window`. e.g.

```
// entry-point.js
import foo from './scripts/foo.js';
window.foo = foo;
```

Or if you want to attach a whole bunch of stuff to the `window` (not just `default`), you can do something like:

```
Object.assign(window, require('./scripts/somelib.js'));
```

You can also take a look at `bundle-loader`, the built-in webpack feature `require.context` or dynamic `import()`s if you want to include some scripts at run-time.

Comment: I needed to run `detect-browser` before main Aurelia app starts. This answer helped me configure this. I just defined another entry with a single module in it which sets a `window` property.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `output.library` in the configuration. From the [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library):

> `output.library`
>   If set, export the bundle as library. `output.library` is
>   the name.
>
> Use this, if you are writing a library and want to publish it as
>   single file.
>
> `output.libraryTarget`
>   Which format to export the library:
>
> `"var"` - Export by setting a variable: `var Library = xxx` (default)
>
> `"this"` - Export by setting a property of this: `this["Library"] = xxx`
>
> `"commonjs"` - Export by setting a property of exports:
>   `exports["Library"] = xxx`
>
> `"commonjs2"` - Export by setting module.exports: `module.exports = xxx`
>
> `"amd"` - Export to AMD (optionally named)
>
> `"umd"` - Export to AMD, CommonJS2 or as property in root
>
> Default: `"var"`

Then you will be able to do

```
myLibrary()
```

Comment: Hrm...there's no way to have multiple compilation targets is there? Ideally I'd like to load my vendor bundle the default way (non-library), and then dynamically load in my page-specific scripts using something like AMD.

Comment: @mpen, this example documents configuring multi-part libraries under webpack. It uses UMD, which should achieve what you want re: direct script tag loading and using an AMD loader like requirejs: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library